# using a pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Hi there I am using meteor js  which is great but i am getting this message on my console .

```
W20161001-16:02:18.321(1)? (STDERR) Note: you are using a pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt.
W20161001-16:02:18.322(1)? (STDERR) While this implementation will work correctly, it is known to be
W20161001-16:02:18.322(1)? (STDERR) approximately three times slower than the native implementation.
W20161001-16:02:18.322(1)? (STDERR) In order to use the native implementation instead, run
W20161001-16:02:18.323(1)? (STDERR)
W20161001-16:02:18.323(1)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save bcrypt
W20161001-16:02:18.323(1)? (STDERR)
W20161001-16:02:18.323(1)? (STDERR) in the root directory of your application.
```

I have node-gyp install globally, remove bcrypt from the packages file and running

> meteor npm install --save bcrypt

to get this error

```
E:\Documents\Development\Projects\recipe-app\node_modules\bcrypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:449:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:404:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\Documents\Development\Projects\recipe-app\node_modules\bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v4.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bcrypt"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.7 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\Documents\Development\Projects\recipe-app\npm-debug.log
```

Dont know what to do next really i am really new to meteor. I am on windows 10 using shell. node v4.6.0  Any help would be great.

Comment: Did you try what the error suggests? 'Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.'

Comment: hey @Aurora0001 thanks for the reply silly of me not to see that thanks a million

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install an appropriate build environment to compile node addons (such as `bcrypt`). This means installing Python 2.7.x and some sort of toolchain.

You could try the [`windows-build-tools`](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools) module which will try to install both Python and the minimum compiler environment via npm (or you can install the minimum compiler environment manually from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159)), otherwise for just the toolchain part there is always Visual C++ Express/Community (Desktop version).

Answer (score 0):

Simply uninstall the package and reinstall it.

```
meteor npm uninstall bcrypt

meteor npm install bcrypt
```

If your `bcrypt` version is > 2.0.0 . You will never see this message again.